# Is it possible to create an application where the user can send themselves push notifications (and be their own push server?)

Tags: android, push-notification, distributed

I have a need to create an application that will consist of two parts, a PC component and an android app component. I would like users to be able to send themselves direct push notifications to the app running on their device, without me having to run a server that they connect to to handle the push. (Going through Google's push servers are ok)

The first issue of getting their device registry key over the PC is a pain but I think it will be acceptable to get them to email it to themselves and then save it to a config file.

The hard part is that it appears they would require access to my google api key in order to push(and this could be abused). I'd like to to come up with something that is "relatively" easy/automated for them to set up and will allow them to use my software to send messages instantly and directly to their device, which may or may not be on the same network.

Comment: What I can say is that if it will already exist,.. probably the android phone is hundred years advanced. hehe.. I can see it possible but not recommended. And why not go client-server based.  it is the most used

Comment: Have you considered a third party solution, RZLTS, Parse, etc where your PC component could call an API that would then target that user/device?